# Making a list from elements of another list turns it into a NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of words using words from a seperate list of words. For example:

```
>>> stuff = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
>>> newlist = [stuff[0]]
>>> newlist
['this']
```

However, I'm running into a problem in my code where I try to do this, and it turns the new list into a NoneType object.

This is the code that is throwing an error:

```
markov_sentence = [stuff[0]]
for i in range(100):
    if len(markov_sentence) > 0:
        if words_d[markov_sentence[-1]] != []:
            newword = random.choice(words_d[markov_sentence[-1]])
            markov_sentence = markov_sentence.append(newword)
        else:
            break
return markov_sentence
```

The variable 'stuff' is a list of string words taken from user input. 'words_d' is a dictionary created earlier, which isn't important right now:

```
stuff = input("Input a series of sentences: ")
stuff = stuff.split()[:-1] #this is here because there was an empty string at the end
```

When I try to run the program, I get this:

```
Input a series of sentences: this is a test this should work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/sbiederm/markov.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "/u/sbiederm/markov.py", line 29, in main
    print(markov(stuff))
  File "/u/sbiederm/markov.py", line 18, in markov
    if len(markov_sentence) > 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Can someone explain to me why the list is being turned into a NoneType? I have tried a variety of methods to try to fix this, but I just can't figure it out.

EDIT:

I have tried this and gotten the same error:

```
markov_sentence = []
markov_sentence.append(stuff[0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\markov.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
 File "C:\Python34\markov.py", line 30, in main
    print(markov(stuff.split()))
 File "C:\Python34\markov.py", line 20, in markov
    if len(markov_sentence) > 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I have looked at other questions, and they do not explain why this is happening in my code. I understand that .append() returns None. This is not what's happening here.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate -_- I looked at the other questions, and they do not answer why this is happening.

Comment: `markov_sentence = markov_sentence.append(newword)` is exactly what the duplicate is about, if you have a different error you should ask another question, there is no way that you are getting a NoneType error if you are checking the len of a list as even an empty list has a length

Comment: I see. I forgot to change the part inside the loop. I didn't notice that until you pointed it out. I thought the problem was something else.

Comment: so we agree it is a dup ;)

Comment: don't know why this was reopened, it is most certainly a dup

Answer (score 3):

The `list.append` method mutates a list in-place and returns `None`.  Meaning, you need to call it on its own line without assigning it to `markov_sentence`:

```
newword = random.choice(words_d[markov_sentence[-1]])
markov_sentence.append(newword)
```

Otherwise, `markov_sentence` will be assigned to `None`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(lst)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3].append(4)
>>> print(lst)
None
>>>
```

Comment: I tried this:
    markov_sentence = []
    markov_sentence.append(stuff[0])

and I got the same error.

Comment: @Steven - Are you sure it is the exact same error and not a different one?  What does the traceback say?

Comment: I added the error message into the question at the end. They are the same.